# Refactor Javascript objects and properties

Tags: javascript, refactoring, abstract-syntax-tree, grasp, esprima

I have some code I may want to refactor many times. Imagine, something like this:

```
Namespace.CustomObject = function(name,type){

  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;

};

Namespace.CustomObject.prototype = {

  writeName: function(){
    console.log(this.name);
  },

  changeType: function(type){
    this.type = type;
  }

};

var object1 = new Namespace.CustomObject('object1','spoon');

object1.name = 'new name';
object1.changeType('new type');
```

So, what I would like is to have a system to generate some sort of data structure where I can know which namespaces/objects I have, and their methods, so I can decide if I want to change "changeType" function name to "setNewType", I can know that it's not just enough with replacing the prototype "changeType" property, but also object1 call to that function, because it is a CustomObject.

So, I have been trying different options.

At first I tried with grasp:

http://graspjs.com/docs/equery/

But I can't find a way to detect the scope of elements, and I think it's not possible.

Then I thought of using esprima to create the AST of my code and maybe get the structure from there that would allow me to identify objects scope, but I can't find a way to do this either.

http://esprima.org/

I guess this must be possible, but maybe I'm trying to wrong way. I know it is also a big task, so of course I'm not asking for someone to solve this, but any hint pointing in the right direction would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: See my essay on "Life After Parsing" (easily found in my bio [click on my name in this comment], or on the web) for why this is hard.  The short answer is that you need lots of supporting machinery for tasks like this, and it mostly doesn't exist in usable form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @IraBaxter.

Anyway I still have the feeling that this must be something you can do. When you run JavaScript code in a console environment (browser debugger or NodejS), objects are allocated in memory, and it knows which functions, properties, etc. are available to each type of object.

Comment: yes, of course it can be done.  The question is, is this machinery available to you in a usable form?  Usually the compiler/interpreter's scheme for managing data is not in a useful form for program manipulation; why should it be, since that is not what those tools do?   That generally means somebody has to make that machinery available in a usable form, and that's where the effort lies.

Comment: OK now I get what you mean. Thanks a lot :)